# Attaching multiple jQuery delegation on element

Tags: jquery, delegates

So, if I have, for example html -

```
<a href="" class="c1 c2">link</a>
```

and than delegate click events like so -

```
jQuery( document ).delegate( '.c1', 'click.ns', function(e) {
 alert(1);
});

jQuery( document ).delegate( '.c2', 'click.ns', function(e) {
 alert(2);
});
```

than I got two alerts. is it somehow possible to detect and prevent others so click event would be executed only once?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first one you can add `e.stopImmediatePropagation()`:

```
jQuery( document ).delegate( '.c1', 'click.ns', function(e) {
  e.stopImmediatePropagation();
  alert(1);
});
```

See demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/jkxTn/